# ModuleNotFoundError happening in Vscode but not in Pycharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pycharm

When I try to import my own modules in Vscode, I always get the ModuleNotFoundError. Meanwhile, when I do this in Pycharm, it works normally.

Both have the same folder structure

[image]

[image]

The code for lib.py is the same for both:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello World")
```

But when I import hello() to main.py, in Vscode, I get the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'lib'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very sorry for being late.

This is because in the Pycharm it defaults selected `Add content roots to PYTHONPATH`(Edit Configurations). This means the parent folder path of `main` and `lib` folder will be added to the `PYTHONPATH`. While VSCode does not take it by default.

You can add this to the settings.json file to achieve this in the VSCode:

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
```